# Loading document issue ....... onlyoffice

Tags: node.js, windows, onlyoffice

I installed onlyoffice locally on my machine windows. Document server running successfully but I open the document loading document appears permanently. All configuration match with provided config at https://api.onlyoffice.com/editors/advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the Document Server has access to the storage and can download the file.
Please specify what you see in the network tab of the browser console.

Comment: i check my network tab in console but there is no error or warning. All files are accessible if i hit the document url directly from browser.

Comment: Please make sure that the file is accessible from the Document Server (not your web browser)

Comment: thanks @ibnpetr after many attempts of installation and debugging on windows at last i solved my issue by shifting document server from windows to Linux and access it from application.